# Native call blocks main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, java-native-interface

I have some Android app that should load some data on start and process it as soon as possible. For better performance data processing done in native code. 
But in some time data amount was increased and it becomes to block UI while processing. The weird thing is that I launch JNI call from background thread and I believe native code should also work in background.
So few questions:

1. how to detect is native code works in main thread?
2. how to detect who blocks UI?

Some code sample:

```
        // java
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              ResourceLoader.loadListsAndParse(); // native call
            }
        }).start();


// c++
void RulesManager::loadRules() {
   if (!rules_loaded_) {
        using namespace std;
        base::FilePath my_dir;
        GetCacheDirectory(&my_dir);
        this->loadRulesInternal(my_dir, true);
   }
}

void RulesManager::loadRulesInternal(base::FilePath& path, bool processExceptions) {
   base::FileEnumerator files(path, false, base::FileEnumerator::FILES);
   for (base::FilePath name = files.Next(); !name.empty(); name = files.Next()) {
        this->loadRulesFromFile(name.AsUTF8Unsafe(), processExceptions);
   }
}

bool RulesManager::loadRulesFromFile(const std::string& filePath, bool processException) {
    bool result = false;
    std::ifstream file(filePath);
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(file, str)) {
        result = this->addRule(str, processException);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Its not possible to help you without seeing actual code.

Comment: @Okas I have added some code sample

Comment: The parts you posted look ok. Native code definitely runs in the same thread that started it, so there must be something else somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android has system calls **getpid()** and **gettid()** defined in **<unistd.h>**. If the **pid_t** return values are equal, then your native code runs on the UI thread.

Comment: I checked it - return values are different, so it works in bg thread. Do you know any other reason how native bg thread could block UI?

Comment: On a single-core device, it is easy to *not totally* lock the UI thread, but to make UI too slow. On multi-core, this would probably involve opening more than one background thread. In your code, if Java starts `loadListsAndParse()` many times, it can end up with too many threads busy with file operations.

Comment: Finally I found an issue based on this answer. I checked all native calls and found that one of them called from UI thread, and it waits until processing started by another native call (on native part) will be finished.

Answer (score 1):

I use [BlockCanary](https://github.com/markzhai/AndroidPerformanceMonitor) for that purposes. If you know about `LeakCanary`, `BlockCanary` provides reports about UI blocking in the same way.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How to detect is native code works in main thread?

You can apply Log method inside your code.

For example your code is:

```
if(myInt > 0){
  doSth();
}
```

Insert Log method;

```
if(myInt > 0){
 doSth();
 Log.i("Info", "if statement is true.");
}
```

now your device will type to the console if your if statement runs. So in your thread, you can insert Log method to critical lines to see if it is running or not.

> how to detect who blocks UI?

As in my first answer, again you can see it from the console if you implement Log methods to your code.

But if you want to do it properly, I suggest you to check Asynctask. This will take time to learn how to implement it properly but the most practical way to pass the long jobs to background in Android is Asynctask.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question. By `native code` I meant C++ code called via JNI.

Comment: Sorry then :) If your native call blocks your onCreate method, again can't you call it inside of an Asynctask?

Comment: I called it inside doInBackground(), so problem somewhere in other place.